# How do you put a if, else statement within a for statement

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

How do you put an `if...else` statement within a `for` statement?

This is the code:

```
// This is within a actionListener. When ever I press a button, this happens.
for (int i = 0; i < booleanVariable.length; i++) {
    //length is 8
    System.out.println("booleanVariable is" + booelanVariable[i]);
    if (booleanVariable[i] = true) {
        booleanVariable[i] = false;
        System.out.println("booleanVariable was true")
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println(" booleanVariable is false");
    }
}
```

This is the output over 3 presses:

```
booleanVariable is true
booleanVariable was true
//correct    


booleanVariable is false
booleanVariable was true
//incorrect.    

booleanVariable is false
booleanVariable was true
//incorrect
```

This means that, for some reason, even if booleanVariable is false, the output says is true, which is false.

What I've found:

- Without the `break;` statement, the program goes around the for all 8 times and outputs exactly the same as without a `break`, only incorrect values another 5 times.

What I've tried:

- Changing the if from true to false (out of desperation)
- If within a While within a For
- else, else if
- case switch

Normally, I'd just use a switch, but I'm using booleans, and booleans dont work is switches.

If someone knows the answer, I'd be forever grateful. Thanks.

Comment: guys, as much as I appreciate your answers, don't answer the exact same thing as the guy before you answered unless it adds something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your

```
if (booleanVariable[i] = true) {
```

to

```
if (booleanVariable[i] == true) {
```

You need to use `==` operator for comparison. One `=` sets the value to `true` which returns always true.
You can also change it to

```
if (booleanVariable[i]) {
```

Comment: you're kidding me. 1 character was missing and it messed up the code. 1000000000 thanks from me, an up vote, and after 10 min, a accept.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem may be in this line:

`if (booleanVariable[i] = true) {`

Boolean comparisons should use `==`, unless you are intending to set the value to true. In any event, this line will always evaluate to true.

Note also that you never really need to compare to `true`, you can simply say something like:

`if (booleanVariable[i]) {`

since if the value is true, the code block will be entered, and if it is false, it will proceed to the else case.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use == to compare the values. Yu use the = that asigns the value true to the variable so it will always be true

```
if (booleanVariable[i] == true)
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an error in the if statement --

You are *assigning* true to the variable, that's why it's outputting true each time.
it needs to be == (equals) not = (assign).

Answer (score 2):

`if (booleanVariable[i])` instead of  `if (booleanVariable[i] = true)`....`=` is assignment operator...you could also use `==` instead

Answer (score 2):

You should change if (booleanVariable[i] = true) as if (booleanVariable[i] == true).
need '==' instead of '='.